# Matching user entered input with regex and trimming the invalid inputs to match regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex : `/^PVER : [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]* [/] [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]* ; 0$/`

let's consider for example that `"PVER : abc / def ; 0"` is a valid input.

If the entered input is : `" PVER     :  abc  //// def   ; 0"`
How do I convert this input to make it valid like in the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex to find multiple consecutive occurrences of `/` and replace it with just one `/`

```js
const res = " PVER : abc //// def ; 0".replace(/(\/)\1+/g, "/");

console.log(res);
```

Or you could modify your original regex to also match multiple consecutive occurrences of `/`

```js
const res = "PVER : abc //// def ; 0".match(/^PVER : [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]* [/]+ [a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]* ; 0$/g);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: using replace like you suggested works perfect. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To turn the second string into the first string, you could replace multiple 2 or more whitespace characters or forward slashes by a single one. Then trim the string to remove the leading space.

```js
let str = " PVER     :  abc  //// def   ; 0";
let res = str.trim()
    .replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ')
    .replace(/\/{2,}/, '/');
console.log(res);
```

Instead of changing the input, you might update the regex. This pattern `[a-z|A-Z|0-9|_]` is a character class which will match one of the many listed. If you don't want to match a pipe `|`, you could write it as `\w`.

In your second example you have to match one or more times a space (or tab perhaps) for which you might use  `[ \t]`, or use `\s` to match a whitespace character and one or more times a forward slash to get match.

Using [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html), you could update your regex to:

```
^\s*PVER\s*:\s*\w+\s+\/+\s*\w+\s+;\s+0$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oLdgLe/1)

```js
[
  "PVER : abc / def ; 0",
  " PVER     :  abc  //// def   ; 0",
  "test"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(s + " =>> " + /^\s*PVER\s*:\s*\w+\s+\/+\s*\w+\s+;\s+0$/.test(s));
});
```